# AAD B2C Get optional custom properties

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have a strange and very unexpected behavior while setting up signup in my application through AAD B2C.
We have set some custom (optional) attributes in our Signup policy. What we want is for our customers to provide them at this time if they can/want, or add them later if the need arise through our user management page.

When a user creates a local B2C account with all custom properties filled, I can get them back and edit them as I please.
But on the opposite if he didn't fill any custom property I can't get them back later.

[image]

in the screenshot I would expect all customers to have the exact same property count, whether those properties are set or not...

The signup is done in our angular frontend using msal.
The properties are then retrieve in our Asp.net Core2 Api using the B2CGraphClient (as mentioned here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)

```
GetAllProperties:
await client
    .GetAllUsers($"$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value%20eq%20%27{userMail}%27)")
    .Map(res => JObject.Parse(res)
        .Descendants()
        .OfType<JProperty>()
        .Select(x => (x.Name, x.Value.ToString()))
        .ToList());
```

If I can't get those properties back is there a way to add them programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the attribute value for an attribute property is set to **null**, then the attribute property isn't written to the **User** object (or, alternatively, [it is removed from the **User** object if it has been previously set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#RemoveAnExtensionValue)).

If you want the attribute property to be written to the **User** object, then I suggest you set the attribute value for it to a default value rather than **null**.

Comment: That would clearly be the best approach but the signup is done on an external page defined in the signup policy, our frontend dev told me he had no control over it

Comment: I could then just write the extension value myself from the back, but with the format : "extension_ab603c56068041afb2f6832e2a17e237_skypeId": "jimbob.skype", I have no idea where to get the guid in the middle. It seems to be the same for every extension of the user, so I could just get the guid from another extension, but if he didn't specify any ….

Comment: Hi @XavSc For the built-in policies, the custom attributes/extension properties are registered to [the **b2c-extensions-app** app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-extensions-app), so you must use the application client ID for this app as the "guid" value in the extension property name.

Comment: that's a strange behavior … I don't really understand why they built it that way, but now that I know where this guid is from I guess I can trick my way out of this through an ugly design … thanks a lot